# VertexAI endpoint cannot connect to HuggingFace

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, huggingface

I'm deploying a model on VertexAI, during intialisation it downloads a public base model from HuggingFace. It uses a custom docker image + model_handler.py file.

- Everything works ok when I run the docker image locally.
- When deployed on vertex, it crashes at the point where it initialises the model. Specifically, when it tries to download the base model from Vertex.

This is the error I see on cloud logs.

`'(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='huggingface.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /microsoft/deberta-large/resolve/main/config.json (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f8c88433190>, 'Connection to huggingface.co timed out. (connect timeout=10)'))"), '(Request ID: .......)')' thrown while requesting HEAD https://huggingface.co/microsoft/deberta-large/resolve/main/config.json`

Any ideas on the cause? Are vertex instances blocked behind a firewall?

I've tried googling but couldn't find a solution.
I guess I could include the artefacts within the docker image but would prefer avoiding this.